# WebAPI 2 - IAuthenticationFilter does not work, but AuthorizeAttribute does - why?

Tags: c#, webapi

I cannot seem to be able to get my custom IAuthenticationFilter to work in WebAPI 2 on .Net standard 4.8.

I create an app using the WebAPI template - with NO security. 
I add the controller with the code listed below- which also contains the absolute most basic implementation of a custom AuthenticationFilter and a custom AuthorizeAttribute.

I can hit the "open" controller end point with no problem.

The other endpoint, I try putting on ONLY the  AuthorizeAttribute, and it works - the Authorize attribute "IsAuthorized" code gets run, and then the controller action. 
If I then replace that attribute with the custom Authentication filter - OR if I add the Authentication filter to it, then my AuthenticateAsync code - and sets the IPrincipal of the context, but then, instead of anything else running, the next call goes to ChallengeAsync and nothing else ever gets run.

What am I doing wrong?

I got the code straight from the many copy-and-pasted blog posts and the MS docs that explain AuthenticationFilter .... or so I thought.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters

Note that I have checked this question:
[Difference between AuthorizeAttribute and IAuthenticationFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668898/difference-between-authorizeattribute-and-iauthenticationfilter)

...but the answer does not address IAuthenticationFilter...

**Code for the test controller is as follows:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;

namespace TestApp.Api
{
    // this is not working currently due to the fact that we have to do the wonky security for aspx pages
    public class TestFilterAttribute : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
    {
        public class BasicActionResult : IHttpActionResult
        {
            private HttpResponseMessage message;
            public BasicActionResult(HttpResponseMessage message)
            {
                this.message = message;
            }
            public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.FromResult(message);
        }

        public bool AllowMultiple => false;

        public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            context.Result = new BasicActionResult(context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Invalid Authorization"));
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>();
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "testUser"));
            claims.Add(new Claim("email", "testUser@test.local"));
            var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Token");
            context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity[] { id });
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }

    public class TestAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext context)
        {
            var principal = context.Request.GetRequestContext().Principal as ClaimsPrincipal;
            if (principal == null) return false;
            return true;
        }


    }

    [RoutePrefix("api/test")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("open")]
        public string TestOpen()
        {
            return "TestOpen Works";
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("secure")]
        [TestAuthorize]
        public string TestSecured()
        {
            return "TestSecured Works";
        }
    }
}
```